# Who should mine the Asteroids? Humans or Robots?

Tags: space, futurology, mines

Discounting the actually quite good idea of having the asteroids be the site of colonization would it be better to use human miners or automated ones?

Both would probably deliver the goods by unmanned rockets. Phosphate to the farms on Venus and Mars. Transition metals to everyone. I think simple assaying, mining, and refining A.I. are completely feasible. As are packaging and shipping.

So what if any human presence is needed in the belt and why?

Comment: Asteroids are far too small to maintain any sort of atmosphere worth even considering. That alone presents serious challenges for any human presence. (Yes, you can bring oxygen, water and other consumables, but sooner or later you run out. Resupply runs are expensive.)

Comment: This is my thought as well but I would like to broaden it. Asteroid miners are a fairly common trope in science fiction.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling While that is true, there are works of sci-fi that have asteroids used as a platform to build spacecraft out of. Given the popularity of multigeneration spaceship theme on WB, one might propose that an asteroid big enough might be used to make such a ship, therefore making it akin to a small, flying temporary colony.

Comment: Curious - why would you consider Humans over Robots?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to fit the tropes of popular fiction.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Cost. Exploited humans could very well cost less than robots that need care and maintenance. Humans of course need care and maintenance, but you can trick and exploit humans so that they bear the care and maintenance costs themselves. And humans are always manufacturing copies of themselves at no cost to their employers (ignoring government required family leave, etc.) See my answer below, especially the example of coal mining.

Comment: I suppose that after a short discussion the robot government will decide that it is too dangerous to send out valuable robot citizens to such a mission. They will send human slaves instead ...

Comment: @ToddWilcox "And humans are always manufacturing copies of themselves at no cost to their employers" - this would possibly be THE reason to use humans. What else are you going to do with all those useless poor people crowding the planet because you couldn't get everyone to control their breeding instincts? (I can easily imagine human lives being considered worthless, or even with negative value)

Comment: @immibis That maybe true. But there is likely going to be a significant dollar value attached to the operation of life support for the first 5 years of these new human units lives, before they can be commissioned for active duty.

Comment: How good are your robots ? With current day technology you would have to use humans (the best available robots took a few years to drive around a few kilometers, without doing anything as complex as mining. They cannot even change their wheels or clean their solar collectors. And they are not autonomous, and remote controlling a mining operation with several minutes lag will not work, etc. etc.).

Comment: It depends, who loses the war will mine the asteroids. With "war" I am referencing something similar as in Battlestar Galactica.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Robots, always robots

**1. NASA mindset is to kill as few humans as possible**

Space is dangerous and evil<sup>1</sup>. Even tiniest error can effectively kill you. Most of the space program is done by NASA and the west. They have the same mindset: *Kill as few as possible*.

It may sound obvious, but during the cold war the Russians had completely different mindset: Get the job done, and if you die in the process, we will celebrate you as a hero.

Yes, I know I am exaggerating here, but the point is that as soon as someone is killed in space, people always ask the question: Is space exploration worth it?

**2. No one cares about a dead machine**

If an unmanned mission fails, the info about it barely makes it to first page of news. Mission success? It will be on first pages if it is something really interesting. Otherwise, no one cares. This is extra plus for robotic missions.

**3. Caution: Living in space may cause health issues**

Consult with your doctor before going to space. Truth is, that we really do not know what the long-term effects of being in low gravity are on a human body. We are trying to figure out the effects on human body, and [we are going to find out pretty soon](https://www.nasa.gov/1ym).

But one we know for sure: Being in space and mining asteroids will definitely have some effects on human body. We know that it will have also some effects on machines. But we do not care about machines (see point 1 and 2).

**In nutshell: We are going to use as many robots as possible.**

I think it is plausible to assume that *some* humans will be involved in asteroid-mining operations, but the people will be dying. So there will be a moral push to replace them with robots and machines.

<sup>1</sup>: It does not mean that space it *intentionally* evil towards anyone. The pure nature of space is that not many live organisms can survive in space without any protection<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>2</sup>: And even when being protected, survival in space is hard. <sup>[citation needed]</sup>

Comment: Depending on the level of technology, there could be a small group of humans on site, to maintain/control the machines, which are replaced regulary (like the ISS crew).

Comment: @Bounce I assumed current Earth, just in the future. Even today [we are able to land small objects](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Rosetta). And as I said towards the end: There might be some humans. But there will definitely be push to replace them by robots or move them to safer places

Comment: I'd argue that space isn't evil, since that implies intent. A more apt description would be that space is indifferent or unaware.

Comment: @Frostfyre English has failed me again. Would rephrasing from evil to *hostile* help you?

Comment: Hostility still implies malicious intent (though [one definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hostile?s=t) is just about habiltability). I'm just being pedantic about this. I took it as sarcasm when I read it. You can leave it as _evil_.

Comment: @Frostfyre What about _hostile environment_ being used quite commonly?

Comment: Who cares about nasa?

Comment: @NPSF3000 I was going to say "children and people that work there" but then I remembered I have a friend who works there and decided not to be rude.

Comment: I can't see a government agency going in for mining operations, but private industry certainly might **if it's cost-effective**. That suggests the answer to the question is, "whichever is cheaper". If asteroid mining could be made to be unskilled labor that can be performed by marginalized, exploited workers who won't demand liability and life insurance, then those workers might have a lower total cost than robots, and that would drive a company to use humans. Or it could be like a gold rush where materials are bought for a price and anyone who wants to go get them can sell for that price.

Comment: Note that coal mining is pretty dangerous with known, almost-certain, long-term negative health consequences, and yet coal mining is still done by humans the world over. Why? Because those humans are powerless, marginalized, desperate for work, exploitable, and cheaper than robots.

Comment: Coal miners are cheaper in their context than asteroid miners in their context.  Asteroid miners means not only sending the equipment (drills) into space (the drill being about three quarters of a robot already) but also the human and oh yeah, *the food, oxygen, water and other things* a human needs to stay alive and sane.  Sending all of that into space is expensive. [citation needed]

Comment: @Draco18s Agreed. Notice that I didn't say that humans would be preferred for mining asteroids, only that *cost would most likely be the primary factor, not safety*. The safety may very well influence the cost (e.g., liability insurance for miners could be expensive), but that still makes safety a secondary concern. Note that if safety were the primary factor for coal mining, *human miners wouldn't be mining coal today*.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Sure sure, just adding some detail.

Answer (score 8):

It's unlikely that a non-communist government would mine asteroids. If private industry found asteroid mining to be cost-effective, then some company would certainly find a way to mine asteroids. That suggests the answer to the question is, "whichever is cheaper". Obviously asteroid mining would have major costs regardless of whether it is done by robots or humans (e.g., delta-v for the mined materials).

Robots would be expensive in terms of development, programming, maintenance, replacement, and more subtly, possible lower effectiveness (e.g., programming might never be good enough to automatically find and extract the purest ores compared to a human). Humans would be expensive in terms of life support (air, food, water, and delta-v for the same) and "hazard" costs. Hazard costs depend on whether the pay and/or benefits would have to be good enough to attract human workers to such a risky business, or whether government regulations would require expensive and heavy safety equipment and/or minimum wages and benefits.

If asteroid mining could be made to be unskilled labor that can be performed by marginalized, exploited workers who won't demand liability and life insurance, then those workers might have a lower total cost than robots, and that would drive a company to use humans.

One likely scenario is that asteroid mining could be like a gold rush where ores are bought for a price and anyone who wants to go get them can sell for that price. It's very likely that after some company builds an infrastructure to mine asteroids, smaller organizations all the way down to private individuals would buy their own mining ships (or mining robots!) and go into business for themselves. Again, the most marginalized might only be able to afford a basic mining ship with a thinner hull (delta-v budget again) and therefore would take higher risks for the chance at striking it rich by staking a claim to an asteroid with great ores.

Note that coal mining is pretty dangerous with known, almost-certain, long-term negative health consequences, and yet coal mining is still done by humans the world over. Why? Because those humans are powerless, marginalized, desperate for work, exploitable, and cheaper than robots. At the same time, automobile assembly is much safer than coal mining, and yet robots are widely used to assemble automobiles. Again, in this case robots are cheaper - perhaps partly due to union contracts and government regulations on treatment and pay of workers, and partly because a robot-assembled auto has a more predictable level of quality and interchangability, which lowers the overall costs of making the vehicle.

One realistic best-of-both-worlds solution would be remote-controlled drones. The distances involved make it very tricky, though. You couldn't effectively control a drone in the asteroid belt from Mars (best case round-trip communication latency is about an hour). What you could do is stake out a territory in the asteroid belt, find the largest rock in the middle of that territory and put a base there. Have drone pilots stationed at that base, which would still be dangerous, but not as dangerous as human miners actually going out to asteroids and blasting and/or drilling. The drones do the most dangerous part of the work, guided by humans who can bring human intelligence to the process. This saves on programming costs, since you don't have to program the entire process, just the menial tasks. It also saves on liability since you can build one facility to keep all the human operators alive that would be much safer than an EVA suit or a mining ship. Plus you have a one-time large delta-v to get the base set up, and then your actual mining drones could be might lighter in weight so long-term fuel costs would be minimized.

Another parallel we can draw from our current economy is that if even **one person** manages to survive and make a large sum of money by going out alone and finding some great asteroid, others will flock to the belt - regardless of safety. The real winners there will be the companies that build and lease the mining ships - "you must sign a full waiver of liability to lease Exploitocorp's VX-3000 Super Mine Commander asteroid mining vessels". In addition, we would likely have more than a few "mining experts" selling their "Easy 12-step guide to outfitting your own mining vessel and striking it rich!"

Comment: This is a great defense of the space miner trope it comes close to convincing me. It is sad that dystopias make more sense.

Comment: I agree that it's sad that such exploitation continues and we don't see an end to it in the near future. If that's dystopia, then I'd say we are currently living in one. Meat slaughter and packing is also a very dangerous job not done by robots. In fact, safety does not seem to be a factor in the choice of robots/drones versus humans in the modern world, except for war, which is a government task, not private industry.

Comment: Human safety is not going to be the reason we don't send people to mine asteroids.

Comment: @King-Ink Agreed, except in whatever way human safety affects costs - if any. And again, there's a difference between **sending** people and people **going on their own**. If I offer you X dollars per pound for platinum and you figure out you can lease a mining ship and buy air and supplies for a month and get Y pounds of platinum on your own, and your costs are less than X*Y, you might just go do it yourself if you have no better options.

Answer (score 4):

Automatize as much as possible.

- Robots are far easier to make radiation-proof and vacuum-proof than humans and can be build for far higher acceleration tolerance.
- Robots require no life support in form of oxygen, food, water, plumbing, clothes or hygiene. All they need when not operating is some electric heating or cooling to avoid damage to electronic components.
- Robots have no psychological needs which need to be met. They need no time off, no entertainment, no contact with family members, have no personal conflicts with each other, are not annoyed by repetitive tasks and feel no claustrophobia when put in a box for several months.
- Putting a robot in serious danger is not ethically questionable (just economically).
- A non-return mission which only involves robots is not ethically questionable.
- Robotic operations scale almost indefinitely. The number of humans who are physiologically and psychologically qualified for space travel is limited, but when you have the blueprints and the factories you can mass-produce as many mining robots as you need.

How much difference these factors make can be easily seen when you consider that it took [a 300 ton rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molniya-M) to get [a 100kg robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_9) to the moon, but [a 3000 ton rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V) for [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Armstrong) [humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Aldrin) of average mass. This simple economic reason is why no human has left Earth orbit for over 40 years.

However, there might be a few things which are hard to automatize. When robots break down, there are limits to what you can do remotely. Remote technology controlled from Earth can perform some maintenance and repair tasks, but sometimes you just need actual hands-on treatment by a human technician. Sure, when you have enough robots you can calculate in some losses due to irreparable defects, but depending on how reliable your robots turn out to be, sending a few humans in a pressurized habitat with them who repair any broken mining robots might be economically justifiable.

Answer (score 0):

If its worth enough for someone to send a ship full of high tech equipment then someone might try and rob the the mined minerals or the high tech equipment.

Since that person might not have sufficient funds for his own little army of space pirate robots he will need to hire humans for the job.

Now you might be able to have a robot security force on the asteroid but human creativity or level of insanity might be something too complex and hard for an A.I. to comprehend.

Therefore you will need a human security force to guard against space pirates.

Comment: Simple: `Identify yourself!` _Code: 1402_ `Incorrect, ratatata` Telecommunication-Identification is of course more complex (a lot of crazy math), but still easily deployable (compared to an off-planet mining facility). And no matter who the approaching party is (human or robot), identifying wrongly results in termination. If there is a human guarding, he might be tricked, be a pirate himself,... My method works because there is no way to sneak in space. You're there or you're not. No rock to hide behind, no tree,...

Comment: "Space pirates" assumes private-citizen interplanetary travel (whether human or robot) is possible.  Currently that doesn't look like a good assumption.  Tracing initial launch and supply missions back to origin is trivially easy too.  Since only a government would send a mining mission, and the only reason to do it is for truly critical resources, interfering with mining is an act of war.  The pirates' Mission Control back on Earth is guaranteed a visit from SAS, SEALs, Spetznaz or whoever.

Comment: @J_F_B_M
Regarding the identification process, if you have a hacker group you can probably bypass it.
You are also assuming communication is always clear like the person is standing near you, it can have interruptions, every situation has a failure point, you don't want to destroy a ship simply because their transmission was partly received.(not to mention the cost of the ship)
Also the pirates can target the ship after it exits the mining facility and then the defenses in the mining facility don't really matter.

Comment: @Graham If we assume interplanetary then the mission control if they indeed require any doesn't have to be based on earth.
Regarding the interplanetary travel, you might start with only governments mining asteroids but I think over time space tourism will also take place.
After that space pirates isn't really that far fetched.

Also I really like saying space pirates.

Comment: It strikes me as entirely implausible that a space pirate would use humans due to lack of funds. Currently, manned missions are *far* more expensive than unmanned ones.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I'll concede that point it is likely sending robots to space will be cheaper than sending humans, however you can come up with another plausible reason why the pirates can't be robots.
For example the government can keep track of all active robots and know who owns them (or even control them with some time delay).

Comment: @Jonathan 1. Of course there will be interference. That's why you can enter your password 3 times before being locked out of an application. The thing is that if you fail to identify and still approach, you're a target. 2. A hacker can trick a computer, but a specialist in rhetoric can trick a human. 3. True, interplanetary ships are targets. Then again, plotting such an encounter midspace with no one noticing? Unlikely. 5. Maybe there are trackers in the robots, but we're talking about criminals. You don't steal a car and leave the tracker inside. 6. Anything else in chat? 7. Space Pirates!!!

Comment: @J_F_B_M
1. My point is that there are multiple failure points you simply can't account for, what if the new authentication codes fail to arrive from earth? What if the facility power goes out due to some sort of mechanical failure?
A human can handle the unforeseen a robot cannot.
2. I disagree with the last part of 2, human soldiers have their protocol and  I doubt an unknown human can simply talk his way into the facility.
3. The plotting of such an encounter depends on the tech level of that time so its the OP role to determine what is possible and how hard to detect such an encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Beside from digging rocks, an effective miner has to perform geological surveys, send probes, analyze results, choose the proper mining spots and techniques. The same with refining - you must design and control the cycle depends on materials you got. That tasks could be harder for AI than just sending bore machines in direction some kind of "ore detector" said and then put all the mined materials into some kind of all-round "ore refinery". Can't see any reasons that could not be controlled remotely though.

Comment: If you know what you are looking for, partially automated partially remote-controlled machines should be plenty deployable. It'd be at an up-front cost, and not quite as versatile as humans, but at *far* lower ongoing cost and *vastly* reduced risk to human life (as discussed by Pavel Janicek).

Comment: It worked in Space Engineers...

Answer (score 0):

Remember [Philae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philae_%28spacecraft%29)? If you are seriously going to do heavy engineering, send humans. The lightspeed communications lag will be several minutes and some tunnel bore or smelter running the wrong way that long can wreck your whole day.

Comment: I have "remember the Philae" tattooed across my back in gothic script.

Answer (score 0):

You use humans in preference to robots when robot technology isn't adequate.  Most particularly the problem solving aspects when things don't work out as expected (and "as expected" is always a rarity in early days).

Since neither technology is adequate right now, it's not possible to answer the question without making presumptions about the state of the technology when somebody decides it must be done.

What's specifically wrong with robots *right now* is that they're dumb and clumsy.  If a problem comes up they won't know how to fix it.  Even if we upload new firmware they won't have the dexterity to fix it.  We won't be able to guide them remotely because of the long round-trip times and low bandwidth for the signal.

Answer (score 0):

If I had a few* billion dollars to invest in space mining my action plan would be

1. Find an average* size rock which can return me good money after mining. It would be economical to risk asteroid than the specially built mining tools, as we have plenty of asteroids.
2. Bring that rock closer to somewhere where it would be easier to mine with remote controlled robots. This can be a moon orbit or even moon surface.