# Why would one live in space

Tags: space, mining

In my world build I want a civilization that lives in space and does astroid mining for resources, to build a giant moon sized AI computer orbiting the planet.

However something i have trouble explaining is why they decided to live in space and stay there, instead of just automating the mining and building process or sending only a part of the population into space (btw, the whole population of the civilization lives in space, orbiting the planet)

What are some plausible explanations for this?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Asking for characters motivation is not really worldbuilding, and the question at the moment is so open ended that every answer is equally valid. Please read our [help] and try to edit it to fit our standards.

Comment: One question you need to answer for yourself is why does the entire population live in orbit of a planet? Was it once inhabited? Is the planet contaminated? Are conditions on the planet naturally hostile to life? Is the planet being terraformed or decontaminated for future habitation? Is the gravity of the planet too strong or too weak? What benefit do they have orbiting a planet? Are they cosmic nomads? Can they only function in near zero gravity?

Comment: Related question: [Who should mine the Asteroids? Humans or Robots?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34360/who-should-mine-the-asteroids-humans-or-robots)

Comment: The answer presumably relates to why they want "to build a giant moon sized AI computer orbiting the planet", which sounds kinda extreme to start with and would need to have it's own motivation - e.g. some cultural obsession or religion or a dictator with an ego problem.  I would have a much bigger problem believing building this AI Moon was sane than believing people wanted to live in space.